# Unable to access local WordPress using the latest MAMP Pro (4.4)

Tags: wordpress, mamp, mamp-pro

I recently updated my MAMP Pro to the latest version (4.4), and now I'm unable to get my local Wordpress up and running. I'm also trying to setup Wordpress on a different Mac and I'm encountering the same issue. I'm able to access my phpMyAdmin with no trouble. I also have my Wordpress directory placed in the the htdocs folder within the MAMP directory. I also have my port settings as following: Apache is at port 80 and port 443 (SSL), Nginx is at port 81 and port 7443 (SSL), MySQL is at port 3306 and my Memcached is at 11211. I'm running Mac Sierra, and the other Mac is running the latest version of High Sierra.

Comment: Can you load up a simple "hello world" php script ok? if so you know php environment is set up ok, so then turn on debug mode in wordpress, wp_config.php (set WP_DEBUG as true) to see possible fatal errors on page, or check php error logs

Comment: In the htdocs directory there is a index.php that is loading when I hit localhost. I was able to add a hello world sample in that file and see it in my browser.

Comment: So MAMP's php/apache appears to be configured correctly if you can echo out some php to the page, so it may be wordpress related. "now I'm unable to get my local Wordpress up and running" - can you elaborate on this..... do you see any errors or is it a white screen when you try to load the wordpress site up in your browser? I'm presuming the wordpress site was fully installed/working prior to the update to MAMP?

Comment: On both Mac's all I'm seeing is the default MAMP screen (the one I edited). It is not loading the WordPress site at all.

Comment: Can you show your filesystem structure? Sounds like the wordpress files are not quite sitting where they should be. You probably wanna put your wordpress files (wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes etc) directly in the root of the htdocs folder and replace any MAMP default files that are there. So it should be: htdocs/{wordpress stuff - wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes etc}.

Comment: I removed all the MAMP files from the htdocs and moved the entire WordPress files in that folder. I tried putting them in a Wordpress folder and just sitting directly in the htdocs folder.

Comment: Did you get a white screen? Any errors showing in the logs? One thing you could check at this point is your database - wherever your files are sitting, your database needs to reflect this (it needs to know the correct site URL) so in wp_options table - rows for "siteurl" and "home" need to have value of correct URL to where you just moved your wordpress installation. If there is a mis-match then the site wont load.